# TaskGroup - Working with tasks from the group

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

Trying to convert some pre-3.11 code to the new TaskGroup way of life, I seem to stumble on some shortcomings...

I try to use it for long-running servers that have several tasks permanently active and some triggered from time to time, based on a program loop within a TaskGroup contextmanager. Maybe it's not the right use-case for this new feature, or I'm missing something...

Basically what I can't find a simple solution for:

- Force the cancellation of all tasks of the group:

  Basically when some condition arise (like for instance a "stop" command received from an API), I'd like to be able to cancel all running tasks and let the program flow exit the context manager and finish.  I can find only 2 options for that:

  - Keep a list of all the started tasks to cancel them myself, which seems redundant to the list already kept by the TaskGroup object (the _tasks property I found is clearly not part of the public API...)
  - raise a CancelledError within the async with block, but then I need to catch it outside of the block to prevent it from bubbling out and allow my function to continue...

  Why not something like a "TaskGroup.cancel_all()" function ?
- catching termination of some tasks within the context manager, without forcing everything to cancel:

  Let's imagine a task that is triggered every now and then to get updated data from an external API. If that one fail for instance because the remote endpoint as a temporary issue, I don't want my whole application to stop, I just want to be able to retry that specific task.  On the other end, if I have another problem and my application is really stopping, I'd like to see that task being cancelled and awaited for as well, so it make sense to start it from within the group...

Am I missing something, or is it just not the right tool for my need ?

Thx !

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I have a similar setup, and struggled with the same problems. After reading the docs and a lot of trial and error, here's how I handled these issues. Happy to get input on a better way to do it if anyone out there has a better understanding.

For your first question, I have a `Restart` exception:

```py
class Restart(BaseException):
    pass
```

A task calling for a restart raises this exception. The `TaskGroup` is wrapped in a `try` block and the following `except` block:

```py
except* Restart:
    log.warning("Tasks canceled from restart command")
```

For your second question, I have each task handling its own exceptions internally. Only unhandled exceptions bubble out and cancel everything.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, if you plan to use this feature for production-ready server, It can be a bad idea.
I'm not a devops/sysadmin, but normally you wait mid-term (6 months, 1 years, more ?) to see if the new version is fully supported by your server provider.

In the documentation you have this :

> The asyncio components that enable structured concurrency, like
> asyncio.TaskGroup and asyncio.timeout(), are implemented using
> cancellation internally and might misbehave if a coroutine swallows
> asyncio.CancelledError. Similarly, user code should not call uncancel.

What you can maybe do, in the case of your call API fails because of remote issue, you can raise a signal https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html with SIGUSR1 or SIGUSR2 for example.
Where you have your TaskGroup defined, you have a signal trap setup. When it receives those signals, you call the `__aexit__()` to stop the task group.

It's just a suggestion, you should maybe dig a bit to find a better solution.